# How to convert torch Tensor/ Storage to a lua table?

Tags: lua, torch

If I have a tensor:

```
t1 = torch.Tensor(2, 2)
```

Is there any way get this data as a Lua table?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a dedicated constructor to [create a tensor from a table](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#torchtensortable) but so far there is no method out-of-the box to convert the other way around.

Of course you can do that *manually*:

```
-- This assumes `t1` is a 2-dimensional tensor!
local t2 = {}
for i=1,t1:size(1) do
  t2[i] = {}
  for j=1,t1:size(2) do
    t2[i][j] = t1[i][j]
  end
end
```

--

**Update**: as of [commit 10f3323](https://github.com/torch/torch7/commit/10f3323) there is now a dedicated [`torch.totable(object)`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/ff11731/doc/utility.md#table-torchtotableobject) converter.